# PHP get JSON key value from specific object

Tags: php, json

Ive got the following JSON:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": "f34c0185-4c9e-40fd-82f6-1d6e9a5d499e",
            "name": "vm01"
        },
        {
            "id": "d671ac7d-3b5a-4777-8510-6e8e58295061",
            "name": "vm02"
        },
        {
            "id": "h59j23cc-9ve2-4508-1277-85y1lo27562m",
            "name": "vm03"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have another JSON that gives me the ID I want to search for.
For example: "d671ac7d-3b5a-4777-8510-6e8e58295061".

I want to search for the JSON Object, that contains that ID and get the value of the name key. I tried with loops and if, else's but I didn't manage to get it working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show you best attempt so far…

Comment: First decode the JSON to a PHP array. Then, use any of the many techniques available to you via googling, to search for a specific item in a multi-dimensional PHP array by its ID. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is not a new problem and probably doesn't need a new question or answer. But if you have a specific problem with your attempts to implement what you've researched, then that might be a different problem and actually worth answering. Please show us your code, then we can understand your exact problem. Make sure it forms a [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decode the json as array object then loop through with the ID that u want to search

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": "f34c0185-4c9e-40fd-82f6-1d6e9a5d499e",
            "name": "vm01"
        },
        {
            "id": "d671ac7d-3b5a-4777-8510-6e8e58295061",
            "name": "vm02"
        },
        {
            "id": "h59j23cc-9ve2-4508-1277-85y1lo27562m",
            "name": "vm03"
        }
    ]
}';

$j = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($j['servers'] as $arr)
{
   if( $arr['id'] == 'd671ac7d-3b5a-4777-8510-6e8e58295061' ) echo $arr['name'];
}
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/0DboX